# .NET TcpClient connected to a VB6 Winsock Control does not close when Winsock control is closed

Tags: vb.net, tcp, vb6, vb6-migration

This problem is a bit perplexing and I tried over and over with Google and Stack Overflow to find an answer.  I wrote a windows service in VB.NET that uses the TcpListener class to listen for connections applications.  It is a fairly straight forward service that simply allows multiple instances of an application to send UDP datagrams to our instruments listening on port 7000.  The reason for the service is because it must listen on port 7001 for UDP datagrams from the instruments, forwarding them along to the connected client applications using TCP.

Anyway, onto my issue.  When the client application is a VB.NET application using TcpClient to connect to the service, everything runs fine.  When the client application closes its TCP connection, the TcpClient in the services cannot receive anymore data (which causes an exception that in turn prompts the service to close and remove the TcpClient in question).  So far so good.

When the client is a VB6 application using the Winsock control to connect to the service, everything is fine until the Winsock control closes the connection.  At this point, the TcpClient.Connected property still reads True and attempting to read the stream does not result in an exception.  Essentially the service still believes that the connection is open.  What's worse is that the callback function for the BeginReceive function in the network stream keeps getting called for the TcpClient that was suppose to be closed.  This causes Process Explorer to show the service ramp up to using 100% of the processor (or a core).  Upon further investigation, Process Explorer reports the connection state as CLOSE_WAIT.

Maybe there is another property or method in the TcpClient class I can check to see if the connection is closed or being closed.  I have not found it so far, though.  Here is a copy of the code for you all to examine.  Maybe you can see where I missed something.  Thanks for taking the time to read this.

```
' Receives the TCP packet from the clients, processes them and forwards them on as requested.
Private Sub ReceiveTcpPacketCallback(ByVal AsyncResult As System.IAsyncResult)
    ' Retrieve the asynchronous state for the callback.
    Dim AsyncState As TcpAsyncState = CType(AsyncResult.AsyncState, TcpAsyncState)

    ' Get the TCP client associated with this state.
    Dim TcpClient As System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient = AsyncState.TcpClient

    Try
        If TcpClient.Connected Then
            Dim CommandData As String

            ' Get the network stream associated with the TCP client that sent the packet.
            Dim NetworkStream As System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream = TcpClient.GetStream

            ' Sync lock the receive buffer to ensure that no other threads are touching it.
            SyncLock m_pReceiveBuffer
                ' End the read to retrieve the data into the locked buffer.
                Dim DataLength As Integer = NetworkStream.EndRead(AsyncResult)

                ' Convert the bytes retrieved into a string using ASCII encoding.
                CommandData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(m_pReceiveBuffer, 0, DataLength)
            End SyncLock

            ' Process the command data that was sent from the TCP client and process the command if complete.
            If AsyncState.ProcessCommandData(CommandData) Then ProcessCommandInformation(AsyncState)

            ' Continue listening for more commands from the client.
            NetworkStream.BeginRead(m_pReceiveBuffer, 0, m_pReceiveBuffer.Length, AddressOf ReceiveTcpPacketCallback, AsyncState)
        Else
            ' Attempt to close the TCP client and remove it from the list.
            TcpClient.Close()
            If m_pTcpClients.Contains(TcpClient) Then m_pTcpClients.Remove(TcpClient)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim Message As New System.Text.StringBuilder

        ' If an exception occurs, assemble the message to write to the event log.
        Message.Append(Date.Now.ToString).Append(","c).Append("ReceiveTcpPacketCallback Exception,")
        Message.Append("Error Receiving Command From TCP Client,")
        Message.Append(ex.Source).Append(","c).Append(ex.Message)

        ' Write the message to the event log.
        Me.EventLog.WriteEntry(Message.ToString)

        ' Attempt to close the TCP client and remove it from the list.
        TcpClient.Close()
        If m_pTcpClients.Contains(TcpClient) Then m_pTcpClients.Remove(TcpClient)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What about pooling for some timeout value in asyncresult?

Comment: I wouldn't bother with checking Connected().  Just go straight to [EndRead()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.endread.aspx) and check `DataLength` as it will return 0 (zero) when the connection is closed. **"If the remote host shuts down the Socket connection and all available data has been received, the EndRead method completes immediately and returns zero bytes."**

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will have to wait until I am back at work to try your suggestions.

Comment: Did you get a chance to do more testing?

Comment: @Idle_Mind Sorry, yes I did.  Your suggest fixed the problem.